# My program only gets the first value of the array and i need all

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, node.js, sqlite

im having a problem in my program. i need to pass all the values of my array to the database. Here is my program..

```js
exports.post = function(req, res){
 var obj = {};
 var eacode = req.body.eacode;
 db.all("SELECT * FROM localarea_listings WHERE eacode= ? ",eacode, function(err,rows2){
 rows2.forEach(function (row2) {
 var hcn = row2.hcn;
 var shsn = row2.shsn;
 console.log(hcn);
 console.log(shsn);
 });
 db.all("UPDATE localarea_listings SET INTERVIEW_STATUS = ? WHERE eacode = ? 
        and hcn =? and shsn = ?",[req.body.INTERVIEW_STATUS, req.body.eacode, 
        req.body.hcn, req.body.shsn],function(err,rows){
  if (err)
    {
    console.log("Error Updating : %s ",err );
  }
  else 
    console.log("Success updating localarea_listings");
  });
 }); 
};
```

The data will process depending on the variable eacode from the database localarea_listings.db

Lets say the values hcn is 1,2,3,4,5 and shsn is 6,7,8,9,10 respectively.

when i print hcn and shsn, the value will display what i want, which is 
hcn=[1,2,3,4,5] and shsn=[6,7,8,9,10]

The problem will starts here, when i update it, it only update the first value of the array which is 1 for hcn and 6 for shsn. i tried using row2[0].hcn and row2[0].shsn but it will cause error..

I hope my question is clear. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the update inside the forEach

```js
exports.post = function(req, res) {
  var obj = {};
  var eacode = req.body.eacode;
  db.all("SELECT * FROM localarea_listings WHERE eacode= ? ", eacode, function(err, rows2) {
      rows2.forEach(function(row2) {
        var hcn = row2.hcn;
        var shsn = row2.shsn;
        console.log(hcn);
        console.log(shsn);
        db.all("UPDATE localarea_listings SET INTERVIEW_STATUS = ? WHERE eacode = ? and hcn = ? and shsn = ? ",[req.body.INTERVIEW_STATUS, req.body.eacode, hcn, shsn], function(err, rows) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error Updating : %s ", err);
          } else
            console.log("Success updating localarea_listings");
        });
      });
      
  });
};
```

Comment: Still have the same problem. it only still update the first value of the array

Comment: what array? did you change the values of `hcn, shsn` in the update query to pass them from the select query not the body?

Comment: I did not change it. do you think my update query is correct to pass many values of data?

Comment: you can optimize the update queries to a single update query

Comment: New problem: when i update the first value of the array, all values changes sames as the first value, but when im trying to update the rest, it doesnt update.

Comment: what array,what values change?

Comment: INTERVIEW_STATUS row values changed.

Comment: the INTERVIEW_STATUS is coming from the page  `req.body.INTERVIEW_STATUS` not the loop so this values should not change in the loop

Comment: Im sorry for that, how will i loop the values for INTERVIEW_STATUS?

Comment: you do another select query